# smbtree on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, smb

Where can I get smbtree for Mac OS X Lion? It came with Snow Leopard and previous versions but it's no longer shipped.

Surely there must be another way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samba daemon was completely rewritten for OSX Lion. You can get `smbtree` back by installing [Samba 3 using MacPorts.](http://forums.boxee.tv/showthread.php?t=38629)

Comment: Thanks Melee. I later realized this too.